# Need some hints for my own WP theme development

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-development

After taking some online tutorials I am willing to create my own custom theme for my myself. This is going to be an online Contact Lense store! So far I have learned how to generate and use Custom Post Types, Custom Taxonamyies, Metaboxes , and Option pages.but there is still one confusing part left for me(hopefully not more! :-))
I need to get some user inputs through HTML Select Options like following image to finalize the users orders: 
[image]

Now my questions are:
1- Do I have to create some thing lik Metaboxes to manipulate these data from users?
2- can I handle these kind of data through simple Form ans Post function in PHP? If so where should I store these data? Do I have to create a table on my own to handle these things?
I really appreciate your time regrading this post,

Comment: Where will this form reside on your web site? If in the admin (which page)? Adding field to the User Profile admin page is pretty easy and does not require much work. [Here is a one guide](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields) I found on Google.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your comment and sorry for concision of using the word " User" instead of Visitor! Actually the form is going to be in front page where the visitors are going to order contact lenses so it is not in admin page for sure, once again thanks

Comment: I assume that the question is getting downvoted because it is very broad. You can do anything in many ways. If you want to get quality answers you should try to be more specific, hopefully show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - Do I have to create something like Metaboxes to manipulate these data from users?

The [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) WordPress function is used on Admin pages, not for front pages. If that is not the "Metaboxes" you are referring to, you will have to explain the term.

> 2 - Can I handle these kind of data through simple Form and Post function in PHP?

Yes. For customer web sites, I often use the [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) plugin. Development time is about the same, but I don't write forms often enough to be certain they are secure. Someone from the future can probably change the form easier too.

> If so, where should I store these data?
>   Do I have to create a table on my own to handle these things?

Where you store the data is up to you. What do you want to do with the data after you receive it? Does that require the data be read in a certain format? We would need a lot more details to help you determine that and the question would probably end up being off topic for WPSE.

The database is an often used option, but there is no built-in table to store data on customers. You would have to add that table (or those tables). WordPress provides the [`wpdb` object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to interface with the WordPress database to create tables and query your own tables.

If you are using an E-commerce plugin or shopping cart to accept payments, it may have a user registration system and the ability to add orders to customers without fussing with the database directly. (Note, I do not know of or recommend any particular e-commerce plugin. I am speaking generally.)

Comment: Charles, I really appriciate your time and perfect explanation.